# How to get the postId in NextJS 13

Tags: next.js13

```
 const fetchPost = async (postId: string) => {
      const res = await fetch(`/api/editpost/${postId}`)
      const post = await res.json()
   }
```

I tried to get the postId in API route like below,  but it is not correct:

```
export const GET = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  const postId = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('postId')
  console.log(postId)
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be done like below:

```
import { prisma } from '@/lib/prisma'
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET(
  request: NextRequest,
  { params }: { params: { postId: string } }
) {
  const postId = params.postId

  console.log('postId' + postId)

  const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: postId,
    },
  })

  console.log('post: ' + post)
  return NextResponse.json(post)
}
```